# Password Grant generate token using HTTR package in R OAuth2

Tags: r, api, oauth-2.0, httr

Brand new to API's and in a bit over my head. Reading a bit and searching around but still confused. I was given the following code to run in curl to generate a token using oauth2 with the password grant. I want to implement this code in R and running into some issues.

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization: Basic xxxyyy123xxx==" -d "grant_type=password&username={username}&password={password}" https://{website}.com/rest/v2/oauth/token
```

When I run the above command in a terminal it generates a token which I have successfully used in R using this code:

```
token <- {character string generated by the above curl command}    
call <- "https://{website}.com/rest/v2/services/APIService/getRegistryRecordByAccessionID?id={id#}"
df <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(content(httr::GET(call, add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", token))), "text"), flatten = TRUE))
```

All I want is to generate the token in R instead of using another program like I have been. This is where my errors come up. The basic format I believe is:

```
token <- oauth2.0_token(endpoint = oauth_endpoint(
                                    authorize = NULL,
                                    access = "https://{website}.com/rest/v2/oauth/token"),
                        app = oauth_app(), #not sure how to set this up
                        use_basic_auth = T,
                        add_headers(Content-type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                                    Authorization = "Basic xxxyyy123xxx==") #not sure if i need the authorization header here, I believe I need the content-type heder
)
```

Comment: If you are just trying to replicate that CURL command, then you don't need `oauth2.0_token`. You can perform a basic request more easily with `httr::POST`. There's also the [curlconverter](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter) package to more directly translate CURL to R.

Comment: How would I go about this with POST using the above CURL command?

Comment: You can try `httr::POST("https://{website}.com/rest/v2/oauth/token", body=list(grant_type="password", "username="{username}", password="{password}"), encode="form")` Check out the help page: https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/POST.html

Comment: @MrFlick I just created that using the curlconverter package you liked to before. Thank you. But this returns a response object that does not contain the token I am looking for to integrate into my GET verb.  Thank you.

Comment: It's very hard to offer specific advice when we can't actually run and test the code. If you are new to `httr`, be sure to read the help pages and available samples. You use `content()` to get data out of the response object.

Comment: content did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From MrFlick's comments above, we can integrate the curl auhtorization commands into a POST using the httr package. We then look at the content of the object this returns which will include the access token in the first item in the list.

```
token <- content(httr::POST("https://{website}.com/rest/v2/oauth/token", body=list(grant_type="password", "username="{username}", password="{password}"), encode="form"))[[1]]
```